# Hebrew Date web request android

Tags: android, api, date, httprequest, hebrew

I am trying to get Hebrew date in my Android app. I could not find an API that I could use.

Edit: How can I integrate the API in to my codes?

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "http://www.hebcal.com/shabbat/?cfg=json&geonameid=3448439&m=50";

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            mTextView.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0,500));
        },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
});
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

UPDATE: Instead of calling hebcal.com, I used http://kosherjava.com/ and downloaded their API into my project. It is providing the Hebrew date for me wihtout any issues.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen the link that you're providing seems ok. 
You should get started by checking the GSON library and the annotations that you can use to create POJOs out of JSON (http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html). 
Basically, you'll replace the handling in **onResponse** with a clever way to obtain the hebrew date out the JSON.
Let me know if you need more details on how to implement it.